# Java, Check if integer is multiple of a number

Tags: java

How do I check if a Java integer is a multiple of another number?  For example, if `int j` is a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use the [remainder operator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) (also known as the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) which returns the remainder of the division and check if it is zero:

```
if (j % 4 == 0) {
     // j is an exact multiple of 4
}
```

Comment: check j!= 0 also as, if j==0 it will result in 0

Comment: @AkhilDad, `0` is still a multiple of `4`.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you can use the module operator for this. For example, in Java (and a lot of other languages), you could do:

```
//j is a multiple of four if
j % 4 == 0
```

The module operator performs division and gives you the remainder.

Comment: Its "modulo", not "module"

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo

whenever a number x is a multiple of some number y, then always x % y equal to 0, which can be used as a check. So use

```
if (j % 4 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//More Efficiently
public class Multiples {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        int j = 5;

        System.out.println(j % 4 == 0);

    }
}
```