# What's the reason for this seemingly overengineered code for checking one number is a multiple of another?

Tags: java, design-patterns, division, integer-division

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8023671/57428) if I want to check one number is a multiple of another I can use the remainder operator `%`.

```
 if( number % anotherNumber == 0 ) {
    number is a multiple of anotherNumber
 }
```

Yet in [this fun project](https://github.com/Mikkeren/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition) which is full of intentionally overengineered code they use the following approach:

```
// int number;
// int anotherNumber;
if ((((int)(number / anotherNumber)) * anotherNumber == number)) {
    number is a multiple of anotherNumber
}
```

which in effect divides `number` by `anotherNumber` and then multiplies it back and checks that the result is `number`.

Does the second approach have any practical meaning or is it just intentionally overengineered?

Comment: (Note that there are apparently obfuscated conditions like this that do handle integer overflow conditions correctly whereas the obvious version does not. Don't simplify that sort of code. At least not until you've moved to a language with sensible integers.)

Comment: The project you linked to is meant to be a parody (and you highlighted as much in your post). I'm pretty sure the answer is that it was intentionally over engineered because that is what the coder was going for. It is probably safe to assume that it has no practical meaning :)

Comment: It would make a difference if `number` is a `long`, `float` or `double` but it's not clear what the type is.

Comment: If you want a real answer and aren't just asking for the sake of posting a StackOverflow question: ask the author.

Comment: @AlexG: Why do I have to ask the author if all I want to know is if this is a recognized design pattern?

Comment: "is it just intentionally overengineered?" - only the code author can actually answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

looks like the Author of the second code did not know the % operator and uses multiplication to verify if there was a remainder part or not :)

Comment: +1, "never ascribe to malice that which can be explained by stupidity"

Answer (score 1):

It follows directly from the definition of the remainder operator (JLS [§15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)) that the two are semantically equivalent:

> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that `(a/b)*b+(a%b)` is equal to `a`.

Therefore, there are no advantages to the more complicated approach.

I can't say *why* the author wrote it the way they did, but the fact that they felt it necessary to cast the result of integer division to `int` may give a hint...

Answer (score 0):

No, this is clearly a case of less qualifications of the programmer. Modulo one encounters in any computer science course on elementary level. The over-engineering may have followed from similar lack of background/practice.

P.S. I would not underestimate the concerned person.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
number = 13
anotherNumber = 4
number / anotherNumber = 13 / 4 = 3.25  // if  number or anotherNumber has type float or double
(int)(number / anotherNumber) = 3
(((int)(number / anotherNumber)) * anotherNumber = 3 * 4 = 12
```

You can see the result is only the same as `number`, iff the the devision `number / anotherNumber` has an integer result.

Therefore

```
if( number % anotherNumber == 0 )
```

and

```
if ((((int)(number / anotherNumber)) * anotherNumber == number))
```

Are true in the same cases. 
I am quite sure, the first version has better performance.

I am quite sure the programmer who wrote the code, did either not knew about the `%`-operator, or did not thought about it in this case.