# Java: How to find if an Integer is a multiple of 2 without using division or modulo operator

Tags: java

This is been answered with `modulo` operator here [Java, Check if integer is multiple of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023659/java-check-if-integer-is-multiple-of-a-number)

I wanted to know if there is a way without using `division` or `modulo` operator.

This is an part of interview question I am trying to solve online for fun

Comment: It talks only about using those operators

Comment: Hint1 - How would you do it just by looking at the number? Hint2 - Look at the **last** digit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that binary representation of even numbers has the least significant bit set to zero. Now the solution is easy: mask the last bit with `1` using bitwise AND, and compare the result to zero. If you get a zero, the number is even; otherwise, it is odd.

```
boolean isEven(int a) {
    return (a & 1) == 0;
}
```

When you do `a & 1`, you get the result that is either 1 or zero, depending on the value of the last bit. The jargon for this is "bit masking": in this case, `1` is used as a bit mask.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 5;

if ((i & 0x1) == 0) {
  System.out.println("It's a multiple of 2");
} else {
  System.out.println("It's NOT a multiple of 2");
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain `0x1`?

Comment: It's `1` in hexadecimal base. In this case, it's just the same as `1`

Comment: Same as 1, but in hex notation. When doing bitwise stuff is easier to use hex notation, but in this case is probably overkill .. just used to it.

Comment: +1 for hex, highly underrated representation nowadays

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shift bit, shift one bit to the right and shift back, which also equivalent to divide by 2 and multiply 2 back

```
boolean isEven(int val){
    if(((val>>1)<<1) == val){
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of going round Robin Hood's barn, but if they want to see several different techniques that might be one of the set.

Answer (score 0):

One of simple method would be like,

```
int no=5;
String str=""+no;

if((str.length()-1).equals("2")||(str.length()-1).equals("4")||(str.length()-1).equals("6")||(str.length()-1).equals("8")||(str.length()-1).equals("0")||) 
  System.out.println("Yes");
  System.out.println("No");
```

As simple as that. Hope it helps.